# GORM list() to return superclass objects only

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a simple object hierarchy, and I want to query each of the objects using list().  The problem is that because of polymorphism, Task.list() returns both instances of type Task and ComplexTask.

```
class Task {
}

class ComplexTask extends Task {
}
```

I realize I can solve my problem by having a common abstract superclass, or filter results based on returned type, but was wondering if there is a way to use dynamic finders and get back superclass instances only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the default table-per-hierarchy inheritance strategy, you can do something like this:

```
Task.findAll("from Task as t where t.class = 'Task'")
```

Comment: +1.  Thanks - you are right, I should have mentioned I am trying to use tablePerHierarchy=false, although I can probably switch to the other other one, since I expect to have relatively few superclass objects.

Answer (score 0):

i think that has to do with lazy loading, because the real instance is not loaded completely not only for relations but also for inheritance.